# Why is two-way binding needed with ngModel when ngModel also uses the DefaultControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular

The DefaultControlValueAccessor takes care of updates in both directions (i.e. updating the input element from the data model and vice-versa). When you a ngModel to an element it also uses the DefaultControlValueAccessor, so I would think that would handle updates in both directions making the actual two way bindings unnecessary. What am I missing? Why do you also  need to two-way bind to the data model -- i.e. `[( )]`?

I realize that you have to have some way to specify which property on from the component class to bind the element to, so at a minimum you'd need `[ngModel]="myField"`, but why do you also need the two-way binding in the other direction? Seems like the DefaultControlValueAccessor would take care of that.

Comment: The DefaultControlValueAccessor only is an "interface". The two-ways-binding using `[(ngModel)]` really is `[ngModel]="variable" (ngModelChange)="variable=$event"`. You can only need one-way-binding (e.g. in a readOnly "control") if only want to show the value -but any change **not** makes the "variable" change-. It's not different to a simple `<input />`.

Comment: @Eliseo, I'm not sure I completely follow what you mean by DefaultControlValueAccessor is only an "interface". It is indeed a directive, and it has a writeValue, which by defaults transforms null values from the data model to empty strings on the input elements. Still, your point about not always needing two-way bindings makes sense, and indeed, if you do not add the event binding (parentheses), it does not update the data-model in that direction.

Comment: Perhaps the ControlValueAccessor's writeValue and onChange methods are not actually even called if the bindings -- i.e. [ ] or ( ) -- are not used.